# How to use the Review functionality after receiving an order

Tags: product, review, transactional-mail

I found, in transactional email a template for a review email. It is not clear to me how I can use that template. How can I send automatically an email to a customer with a link to a review about our shop, order or products?

Comment: Wouldnt this help you?https://www.ashsmith.io/2014/08/28/custom-transactional-emails-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

Use Mandrill extension, create a mandrill and mailchimp account, integrate with your magento. Edit your mail templates and you are ready.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Kiyoh](https://www.kiyoh.nl/) or [Trustpilot](https://www.trustpilot.com/). These have a system already that you can implement in Magento.

An email will be sent by them to your customer pursuing him/her to do a review for your shop/order. Both parties are well known and trusted by consumers so when you work with either Trustpilot or Kiyoh then this will make your customers to trust you even more.